# SVN working fine and then "svn: OPTIONS 200 OK" error and "does not exist"

Tags: svn

SVN was working just fine until a few minutes ago -- I can still browse my repository at http://svn.example.com/myrepo but when I try to perform any operation, including svn up, I get:

```
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://svn.example.com/myrepo': 200 OK (http://svn.example.com)
```

And when I tried `svn cleanup http://svn.example.com/myrepo` just to see what would happen, I got:

```
svn: 'http://svn.example.com/myrepo' does not exist
```

Again -- typing that into the browser, I can still browse the repository just fine. Whats going on??

Comment: Are you absolutely sure youre typing the same thing into the browser as you are in the CLI. I know ive gotten wound up on 40 minute adventures before all because i was using `.net` instead of `.com` or because i was missing a path segment in my url :-)

Comment: Shouldn't you repo's url be "http://svn.mywebsite.com/svn/myrepo" ?

Comment: @prodigitalson: I'm not typing anything in the CLI, except for the "cleanup" line, which I pasted from the clipboard just as I did in the browser. The "svn up", "svn info", and other commands I've tried are just operations on the existing working copy. It was working, and then it wasn't. I changed nothing.

Comment: @pmod: No. I setup these repositories myself, and I wouldn't set it up that way, as that would be redundant.

Comment: Correction, "svn info" works fine, its just "svn up" thats giving me the 200 OK error. Must be that my working copy is fine, but somethings screwy on the server?

Comment: Does the "svn checkout" works for this url?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out the solution to this problem was very basic – *and also very complicated.*

**The simple answer:**

The hostname `svn.mywebsite.com` does not exist (at least, not as far as my development server is concerned).

For anyone else who's getting this problem, I strongly advise approaching the problem from the assumption that for whatever reason, your client simply cannot locate the SVN server.

--

**The complication:**

Now for me, it turned out to be a little more complex, because as I mentioned before, it WAS working -- and then it stopped.

The reason for this, in case you are interested, is that our SVN server lives on a web server along with our main application (located at `http://www.mywebsite.com`), which happens to be *mirrored on another server,* and the DNS records for `mywebsite.com` are being distributed on an A-B pattern between the two servers. Since the SVN client on my development server couldn't find `svn.mywebsite.com`, it was looking for simply `mywebsite.com`. Once it connected to the "A" server, where the virtualhost records exist for the SVN server, Apache took over and served the content appropriate to `svn.mywebsite.com`.

But at some point, my DNS cache was refreshed, and with no application logic available to quietly send the user back to the "A" server, my development server began resolving `mywebsite.com` to the "B" server -- where SVN hasn't even been installed.

Obviously, that's when the SVN client started saying "uh, gee, there ain't no such server." (Who knew thats what OPTIONS blah blah 200 OK meant?)

**Why I'm an Idiot**

Here's where the inevitable `ID10T` error comes into play. The reason I could consistently browse to "http://svn.mywebsite.com/myrepo" in Firefox, was because I had manually created a host entry on my PC pointing to the IP address of the "A" server.

If I'd remembered that sooner, I would have saved myself a lot of time – and a few precious Ibuprofen tablets. :)

Answer (score 8):

Similar problem here, with a different cause and solution.

**The simple answer**

Downgrade the Subversion client.

**The more complicated answer**

Previously, I'd been using 1.6.11 (particularly `1.6.11-SlikSvn-tag-1.6.11@935062-X64`) and that worked fine. Upgraded to 1.6.17 (`1.6.17-SlikSvn-tag-1.6.17@1130898-X64`) and then started getting the `OPTIONS of ... 200 OK` error.  Downgrading again fixed it. All this was made more confusing by the fact that (obviously) I could still browse the repository in my browser, and also in IntelliJ which, I assume, uses its own SVN client.

**Why I'm an idiot**

Since I work across two SVN repositories, and the other one works fine with both versions of the client, I didn't notice the problem until a few days after I upgraded, so I didn't immediately figure out the cause. If I'd realised that sooner, I would have saved myself a lot of time - though I stopped just short of hitting the painkillers!

*</shameless plagiarism of Brian Lacy's answer>*

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue after upgrading my SVN server to 1.7

I fixed this by adding the following to my apache location directive:

```
  SVNAdvertiseV2Protocol Off
```

Comment: I'm trying to locate that directive without luck, can you tell me where to find it exactly?

Answer (score 3):

This "svn: OPTIONS of" error can also show up if your server uses the svn port but you specify the http protocol on your url.

That is, I would get the error when I tried:

```
svn checkout http://genericsite.com/someproject/trunk someproject
```

but what I ought to have been doing was:

```
svn checkout svn://genericsite.com/someproject/trunk someproject
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem cause I tried to add a second SVN Repo. After reading this post, I recognized, that I had to add another **Location** set in my SVN Config-File (in my case: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf) with different paths. Now its working after restarting Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Why not one more solution for a ridiculously ambiguous error message? In my case, the SVN repo was created by the root user so permissions were wrong.

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/svn/foo
```

And, since I'm running SELinux, I also did this for good measure:

```
chcon -R system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www/svn/foo
```

ETA:

An easy to spot symptom of this problem is in your Apache logs. Note, no body sent in response to the OPTIONS request:

```
"OPTIONS /rancid HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "SVN/1.6.11 (r934486) neon/0.29.3"
```

After the changes:

```
"OPTIONS /rancid HTTP/1.1" 200 97 "-" "SVN/1.6.11 (r934486) neon/0.29.3"
```