# SVN Commit POST of '/svn/repo/!svn/me': 200 OK (http://xx.xx.xx.xxx)

Tags: linux, svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to make a svn on linux server, so that our developers will just commit their files using tortoise svn, but I'm having issue when I'm trying to commit a file. We can check out and update the svn repo but we cannot commit our files

[image]

Anyone who has fix with it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638276/svn-working-fine-and-then-svn-options-200-ok-error-and-does-not-exist

Comment: I'm using the ip address as the root url